# Use case diagram extend or include for admin relation to customer order

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

So basically i'm wondering if I'm thinking correctly. In an e-commerce environment does the order of a product have a relationship to the admin use case of managing orders? Once an order has gone through  is the admin then going to be able to see the order through a relationship between the 2 use cases. I've provided an image for reference in my case.[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3ta.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

No, there is no extension here. Those will be two separate UCs.

### Explanation

First let me focus on the goal of the Use Case diagram. This diagram is intended to show functions of the system and users (or more broadly actors) engaged in those functions. It is not used to show how data flow through the system or what are steps of the processing. There are other diagrams to do that.

As a rule of thumb, something is a good use case if you can log into the system, perform only the action of this single use case and then log out.

Extends (Includes works pretty much the same, it's just stronger) means that when you run the extended UC you can include the other use case as well. In other words in your specific example when Customer logs to E-Commerce to place an order he can while placing an order also choose to additionally receive and manage order (BTW I would reconsider this UC, you probably have few separate UCs here like `Complete order`, `Dispatch order` or `Reject order`) in which case additionally an Admin is need. Even if you invert Extends, it's still not what you want. Those two UC happen totally separately even though the order processed by Admin is the very same one placed by Customer.

Comment: Explained it perfectly thank you! It all makes sence now :D

Answer (score 0):

I did not search for too long but I did not find a case where a given use case, associated to one actor, is extended or included by another use case, associated to another actors.

A use case describe the usage of your system by a given actor so you do not have any other actor involved.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So therefor they do not need a relationship? I can just simply remove the extended relationship?